# how to update geometry vertex position in three.js r58?

Tags: geometry, three.js, updating, vertex

in the version r56 of three.js this was working

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
```

in the new r58 version  it is not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The [migration docs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration#r56--r57) explain API changes between versions:

If you are using *BufferGeometry*, `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate` has been changed to `geometry.attributes.index.needsUpdate`.